# Two consecutive fwrites operation

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I have a file opened in the write mode as shown below:

```
int a = 10;
char b = 'm';
int y = 0;
char z;

FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen("/config/gps_backup.dat","w");
```

I am doing a frwite of two variables on the file(the first one is an integer and second one is a character) as shown below:

```
fwrite(&a,1,sizeof(int),fp);
fwrite(&b,1,sizeof(char),fp);
```

1. Will two consecutive fwrite operation overwrite each other
2. If not, can two consecutive fread operation populate properly into
   my variables

for eg:

```
fread(&y,1,sizeof(int),fp);
fread(&z,1,sizeof(char),fp);
```

Can y and z variable hold the value of 10 and 'm' if consecutive fread operations are done.

Tha

Comment: Your full code ? Does your read operations are executed just after write operations or when ?

Answer (score 5):

Two consecutive fread or fwrite should not cause any problem as long as they are not done parallelly.

The system will maintain the seek pointer in the FILE * and ensure that you get correct data written and read during consecutive fwrites and freads.

You can refer to the [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fwrite/) for more details.

It clearly states the below in the RETURN VALUES section

```
 The functions fread() and fwrite() advance the file position indicator
 for the stream by the number of bytes read or written.  They return the
 number of objects read or written.  If an error occurs, or the end-of-
 file is reached, the return value is a short object count (or zero).
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the consecutive writes will not overwrite each other.  They are performed on the same file descriptor and the operating system keeps track and does not overwrite.  As for the reads, as long as you do not close the file descriptor between reads, the two reads will populate you variables correctly, given you parse the sizes correctly.

Comment: @Cytinus..So if i had done two fwrite operation  with 1st variable written as integer and the 2nd variabe written as character.The 1st fread operation would give me integer and the 2nd fread operation would give me character right?

Comment: No, fread will treat whatever it is passed as a character buffer.  You may need to do something like: `yint = atoi(y);` to get the integer value.

Comment: @cytinus There's definitely no use for `atoi`, since `fwrite` and `fread` work binary.